# Infura Ethers.js jsonrpcprovider failed to detect network and cannot start up

Tags: ethers.js, infura, web3-providers

I have tried to make Ethers.js 6.8.0 to work with Infura:

```
    endpoint = "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/" + infuraApiKey;
    provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(endpoint);
```

but got this error:

```
POST https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/1234... 403 (Forbidden)
JsonRpcProvider failed to detect network and cannot start up; retry in 1s 
(perhaps the URL is wrong or the node is not started)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with Ethers.js 6.8.0 and Infura:

```
network = "sepolia"
infuraApiKey = '1234...'
provider = new ethers.InfuraProvider(network, infuraApiKey);
```

InfuraProvider() does not behave the same way as JsonRpcProvider()

JsonRpcProvider() is used for Ganache/Hardhat/Foundry

Ohter Ethers.js providers for Alchemy and QuickNote:

```
provider = new AlchemyProvider(network, apiKey)
provider = new QuickNodeProvider(network, token)
```

Use different methods to make a new provider: https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/providers/thirdparty/

An old example of using Infura with Ethers.js: https://community.infura.io/t/react-js-ethers-js-demo-of-using-the-infuraprovider-vs-the-metamask-wallet-web3provider/6108